TeXShop Autocomplete to Nonsense Units
Recently while using TeXShop (Version 5.46) on my MacbookPro (running the latest version of Sequoia) when I am typing, terms are autocompleted to complete nonsense. It does not happen all the time, but when hitting space after '=' something tends to autocomplete to gibberish, typically some units in degrees Celsius or Fahrenheit (complete with the $\circ$ symbol) or other units, e.g. when I typed 'W(1)=' and hit space it autocompleted to '0.0569 BTUs/min.' There are occasions where it will do actual Mathematics, e.g. when I typed '12400 - 15400=' it autocompleted on space to '-3000.'
I cannot tell why this is happening and how to turn it off. I cannot find a TeXShop setting that allows this to happen. I then assumed it was the Mac, and went to System Settings, Keyboard, Text Input, and turned off the predictive text. But the problem persists. Is this a TeXShop issue, a Mac issue, or both? How do I prevent these nonsense autocompletes?

Since you are on Sequoia, the behavior you are describing most likely refers to the new Math Notes feature: When Sequoia interprets your typing as a calculation attempt because of the presence of the equals sign, it offers an answer.
As this is a new feature in Sequoia, not all applications have settings to customize it. In Notes, for example, one can go to Format->Math Notes to alter its behavior. Apparently TexShop does not have this option. You can try the following workaround: Continuing to type after the equals sign should normally cancel the automatic substitution (except when Space or Enter is pressed, which amounts to accepting the substitution). Alternatively, pressing Esc when the substitution appears should cancel it.
If you wish to like to disable Math Notes for good for your whole system, you can do so by heading to the Apple Menu and following Settings -> Screen Time -> Content & Privacy -> Intelligence & Siri and turning off Math Results.
