MacOS Sequoia 15.1 autocompletes interfere with LaTeX
In most text boxes on MacOS 15.1 Sequoia, typing e=  autocompletes to e=2.718 and typing pi=  autocompletes to pi=3.142. In particular, variations like $\pi=$ and $e=$ do the same. As you might imagine, this is quite infuriating when trying to write a document in TeX. Does anyone know how to turn this "feature" off?
I think I'm probably just not searching for the right keywords, so I hope this is an easy fix! Thanks!
I am using TeXShop Version 5.46 on MacOS Sequoia 15.1. I have turned off Siri, Apple Intelligence, Spell Check, etc. I should note that this occurs in other text boxes in other apps too, and is not localized to TeXShop.

This might be a duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/728478/texshop-autocomplete-to-nonsense-units

Also related:
https://discussions.apple.com/thread/255789918?sortBy=rank
https://discussions.apple.com/thread/255806670?sortBy=rank

As this is a new feature in Sequoia, not all applications have settings to customize it. In Notes, for example, one can go to Format->Math Notes to alter its behavior. Apparently TexShop does not have this option. You can try the following workaround: Continuing to type after the equals sign should normally cancel the automatic substitution (except when Space or Enter is pressed, which amounts to accepting the substitution). Alternatively, pressing Esc when the substitution appears should cancel it.
If you wish to like to disable Math Notes for good for your whole system, you can do so by going to the Apple Menu and following Settings -> Screen Time -> Content & Privacy -> Intelligence & Siri and turning off Math Results.

Thanks! That worked for me. Absolutely absurd that it's buried so deep in the screen time menu.

This behavior now turned off by default in TexShop 5.48. The documentation says that one should issue the command "defaults write TeXShop MathExpressionCompletion 1" in Terminal to turn it back on.
